# schedule cron job executed twice in different time (AWS Beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use AWS Beanstealk php worker environment.

I managed my cron jobs in cron.yaml

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "prepare-technical"
   url: "/workers/cron/event/prepare/technical"
   schedule: "45 0 * * *"
```

And I didn't understand why but, this cron is executed twice times and in differents hours :

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [24/Mar/2017:00:44:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [24/Mar/2017:00:52:43 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"

127.0.0.1 (-) - - [25/Mar/2017:00:44:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [25/Mar/2017:00:49:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"

127.0.0.1 (-) - - [26/Mar/2017:00:44:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [26/Mar/2017:00:53:23 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"

127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Mar/2017:00:44:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [27/Mar/2017:00:50:35 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"

127.0.0.1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2017:00:45:00 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [28/Mar/2017:00:50:00 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"

127.0.0.1 (-) - - [29/Mar/2017:00:44:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [29/Mar/2017:00:50:16 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"

127.0.0.1 (-) - - [30/Mar/2017:00:45:00 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [30/Mar/2017:00:50:21 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/event/prepare/technical HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
```

Do you have an idea how can I fix that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, jobs will be re-posted if your web server doesn't respond within five minutes. There are a few possible approaches:

1) Increase the "Inactivity Timeout" under Configuration/Worker Configuration/Advanced Options. The maximum value is 1800 (30 minutes.)

2) Make your jobs run more quickly by adding processing power or splitting them into smaller chunks.

3) When you receive a job, execute it in a background thread and return from the main thread immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My cron is very simple and fast (max 45 sec to be executed) and return a Response when it's finished. How can I do your 3) ?

Comment: If your jobs are really that quick, then putting them in background threads will only add complexity without solving your problem. Are you returning a `200` when your job is complete?

Comment: Yes `return new Response(null, 200);` <= it's with symfony (body, statut). So, I don't understand why my cron is executed second time. I was trying with Postman and my code return statut: 200 and time : 18sec.

Comment: I resolved my problem when I send message body with my 200 statut (before I return null)